# How to use weekly time series in Python

Tags: python, stata

I am using `.dta` data in Python.

In Stata my time variable is looking like this:

```
2000w1
2000w2
2000w3
2000w4
2000w5
2000w6
2000w7
...
2000w50
2000w51
```

In python, I can not obtain this format anymore, but automatically Python reads it as daily, like:

```
2000-01-01 
2000-01-02
```

How can I get the same (weekly) time variable as it was in Stata?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Watch out, as Stata weeks run 1 to 52 in any year, the last week being 8 or 9 days long. See e.g. https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0052 for more.

Comment: Do yo have access to Stata? It may be better to save the datatime column as string before importing in Python so you can deal with the conversion yourself

Comment: Yes I have access to the dataset in STATA.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example where I read in some dates, flip them to weeks, and then extract the first day of the week. I'm using Stata 17 and Python 3 (anaconda).

```
// read in a few raw dates
input date
-4191
12724 
12672  
13100
end
// format them as daily dates
format date %td
// make a weekly date and format
generate weekly = yw(year(date),week(date))
format weekly %tw // now we have data like yours
// get the day that the weeks starts (Wouter's idea)
generate datefromweek = dofw(weekly)
format datefromweek %td
save dates.dta // this is what we'll read into python
```

Then we can switch to Python and load them:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_stata("dates.dta")
df.head()
df.dtypes
```

yields:

```
        date     weekly datefromweek
0 1948-07-11 1948-07-08   1948-07-08
1 1994-11-02 1994-10-29   1994-10-29
2 1994-09-11 1994-09-10   1994-09-10
3 1995-11-13 1995-11-12   1995-11-12
```

and

```
date            datetime64[ns]
weekly          datetime64[ns]
datefromweek    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

So Pandas seems to understand the weekly dates just fine.
If this doesn't help, then you'll need to provide more information about how you are loading the data into Python.

Comment: @E_Caggiano if this answers the question, feel free to accept it.